Are the continuous map's slices continuous?conversely?
I'm just a student studying general topology.  Maybe the questions are easy: 
If  : ℝ2 → ℝ is continuous, are all of its slices $(, ) : ℝ → ℝ$ and $(,) : ℝ → ℝ$ for  ∈ ℝ continuous? What about the converse statement?(all with standard topology).

My thoughts:

The first is true,by the definition I proved the original image of open sets are open.

For the converse,I guess it's wrong.My counterexample is $ f(x,y)= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq(0,0)$,$f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$.In analysis we have known it's not continuous in $ℝ^2$ because when points close to $(0,0)$ in different directions,the limits are differernt;While it's slices are continuous.



My questions:

Is the converse right?
Could you give me some topology reason show that my exmaple is not continunous in the whole plane,like some open set's orignal image is not open?


Another way to see that slices of continuous functions are continuous is to see that $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ for some fixed $y$ is just the composition of $f$ with the inclusion map p $\iota : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $\iota(x) =  (x,y)$. And as both are continuous, so is their composition.
The converse is not true however and you have given a perfect counterexample and computing limits to show discontinuity is a valid "topological reason". I will however also give a pre-image argument. Consider the closed set $A = \{\frac 1 2\} \subseteq \mathbb R$. What is its pre-image?
$$f^{-1}(A) = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} \,\bigg|\, xy = \frac{1}{2} (x^2 + y^2)\right\} = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} \,\bigg|\,0 = (x - y)^2\right\}$$
which is the positive diagonal $x = y$ without the point $(0,0)$, hence not closed. But the pre-images of closed sets under continuous maps are closed, therefore $f$ cannot be continuous.

Thank you, you really provided a very simple example. I don't know why I didn't think of it. I've been looking for an open intetval's preimage, but I've found that it always seems to be open.

I think that for any open interval $I \subsetneq \mathbb R$ containing $0$ the pre-image is not open, as it contains $(0,0)$ but no neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. So these would also work, although the computation is a bit longer. I you want, I can add such a computation to my answer.
Also, if you are satisfied with any answer, please consider accepting one.

I considered (-1/2,1/2) and (-1,1),I failed ,so did (0,1).Your choice is nice.Thank you so much. @Sven-Ole Behrend

Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\times Y\to Z$ be a function. Here, $X\times Y$ is endowed with the product topology.
Everything you have written is correct. Continuity of $f$ (which is sometimes called "joint continuity" because it is jointly continuous in both of its input variables) implies separate continuity (continuity of the functions $f^x, f_y$, where for a fixed $x$, $f^x(y)=f(x,y)$ and for a fixed $y$, $f_y(x)=f(x,y)$). This is true for any topological spaces $X,Y,Z$
I would like to offer another proof that joint continuity implies separate continuity. Not that it's better or worse than your proof involving open sets. It just provides another way of thinking about the problem. I think there is value in both methods of proof.
For a fixed $x$, by definition of the product topology, $i_x:Y\to X\times Y$ given by $i_x(y)=(x,y)$ is continuous. Then the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is equal to $f\circ i_x$, which is the composition of continuous functions, and is therefore continuous.
Now let's give the intuition for why joint continuity implies separate continuity, but separate continuity does not imply joint continuity. Continuity (which, in this setting, is joint continuity) of $f$ means that for $(x_0,y_0)\in X\times Y$, as $(x,y)$ approaches $(x_0,y_0)$, $f(x,y)$ approaches $f(x_0,y_0)$ (in a way that can be made formal with nets/open sets). Joint continuity means that this is true, no matter how we approach $(x_0,y_0)$. However, continuity of $y\mapsto f(x_0,y)$ at $y_0$ simply means that $f(x,y)$ approaches $f(x_0,y_0)$ as we approach "along a vertical line". Similarly, continuity of $x\mapsto f(x,y_0)$ at $x_0$ simply means that $f(x,y)$ approaches $f(x_0,y_0)$ as we approach "along a horizontal line". Since the latter only deals with a (proper) subset of the ways to approach $(x_0,y_0)$, it does not guarantee that $f(x,y)$ approaches $f(x_0,y_0)$ for all ways to approach $(x_0,y_0)$.
EDIT: How do we know that $i_x:Y\to X\times Y$ is continuous? It depends on how we want to define the product topology. We can define it to be the set of all arbitrary unions of members of $$\mathcal{B}=\{A\times B:A\in \tau_X, B\in \tau_Y\},$$ where $\tau_X$ is the topology of $X$ and $\tau_Y$ is the topology of $Y$. Using this definition, in order to check continuity of a function $g:U\to X\times Y$ (where $U$ is any topological space), it is sufficient to check that $g^{-1}(A\times B)$ for each $A\in \tau_X$ and $B\in \tau_Y$. This is because a general open set $U$ in the product topology has the form $$U=\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}A_\gamma\times B_\gamma,$$ and $$g^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma}g^{-1}(A_\gamma\times B_\gamma)$$ is open if each $g^{-1}(A_\gamma\times B_\gamma)$. I'll state and leave it to you to check that for a fixed $x\in X$ and open sets $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$, $$i_x^{-1}(A\times B)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\varnothing & : x\notin A \\ B & : x\in A.\end{array}\right.$$
Another way to check is the following: A function $g:U\to V$ is continuous if and only if for each $u\in U$ and each open set $C\subset V$ with $g(u)\in V$, there exists an open set $D\subset U$ such that $D\subset g^{-1}(C)$ (I'll also leave it to you to check this characterization). We'll also use the fact that $C\subset X\times Y$ is open if and only if for each $v\in C$, there exist open sets $A\subset X$, $B\subset Y$ such that $v\in A\times B\subset C$.  Putting these together, fix $y\in Y$. Then $i_x(y)=(x,y)$. Let $C$ be an open set containing $(x,y)$. There exist open sets $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$ such that $(x,y)\in A\times B\subset C$. This implies that $x\in A$.  Then $$B=i_x^{-1}(A\times B)\subset i_x^{-1}(C).$$  Thus $i_x$ is continuous.
Another way to do it would be to check nets. If $(y_\lambda)$ is a net in $Y$ converging to $Y$, then $i_x(y_\lambda)=(x,y_\lambda)$ converges to $i_x(y)=(x,y)$ in the product topology.
Finally, if $W$ is a set and $\mathcal{S}$ is a set of subset of $W$ such that $\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{S}}R=W$, then the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$, which we denote by $\tau_\mathcal{S}$, is the set of all arbitrary unions of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{S}$. In other words, $$\tau_\mathcal{S}=\Bigl\{\bigcup_{\gamma\in T}\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}A:T\subset \mathcal{S}^{<\omega}\Bigr\},$$ where $\mathcal{S}^{<\omega}$ denotes the set of all finite subsets of $\mathcal{S}$. One can check that 1. this is a topology, if $\tau$ is any other topology on $W$ such that $\mathcal{S}\subset \tau$, then $\tau_\mathcal{S}\subset \tau$. In other words, $\tau_\mathcal{S}$ is the coarsest topology on $W$ which contains each member of $\mathcal{S}$.
If $U$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of functions $f:U\to V_f$, where $V_f$ is a topological space that may or may not depend on $f$, one is often concerned with the coarsest topology on $U$ which makes each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ continuous. Of course, such a topology must contain each member of $$\mathcal{S}=\Bigl\{f^{-1}(W):f\in \mathcal{F}, W\subset V_f\text{ open}\Bigr\}.$$  Since $\cup_{A\in\mathcal{S}}=U$, one can check that the coarsest topology on $U$ making each $f\in \mathcal{F}$ continuous is exactly $\tau_\mathcal{S}$ for this $\mathcal{S}$. In this case, if $W$ is a topological space and $h:W\to U$ is a function, then $h$ is continuous (where $U$ has the $\tau_\mathcal{S}$ topology) iff $f\circ h:W\to V_f$ is continuous for each $f\in \mathcal{F}$. Indeed, one direction is clear: If $h$ is continuous, then since each $f\in \mathcal{F}$ is continuous, each $f\circ h$ is the composition of continuous functions, and is therefore continuous. On the other hand, suppose that each $f\circ h:W\to V_f$ is continuous. Then for each $f\in\mathcal{F}$ and each open subset $W$ of $V_f$, $$h^{-1}(f^{-1}(W))=(f\circ h)^{-1}(W)\in \tau_W.$$  This shows that $$\{h^{-1}(A):A\in \mathcal{S}\}\subset \tau_W.$$ Then for any $T\subset \mathcal{S}^{<\omega}$, $$h^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcup_{\gamma\in T}\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}\Bigr)=\bigcup_{\gamma\in T}h^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}A\Bigr)=\bigcup_{\gamma\in T}\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}h^{-1}(A)\in \tau_W.$$ This set is in $\tau_W$ because, as we just showed, each $h^{-1}(A)\in \tau_W$, so each $\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}h^{-1}(A)\in \tau_W$, because $\tau_W$ is closed under finite intersections, and $\bigcup_{A\in \gamma}\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}h^{-1}(A)\in \tau_W$, because $\tau_W$ is closed under arbitrary unions. Since an arbitrary member of the product topology on $X\times Y$ has this form $\bigcup_{\gamma\in T}\bigcap_{A\in \gamma}A$, and the preimage of any such set under $h$ is open in $W$, $h$ is continuous.
Another equivalent definition of the product topology is the coarsest topology on $X\times Y$ such that the projections $\pi_X:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_Y:X\times Y\to Y$ given by $\pi_X(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_Y(x,y)=y$ are continuous. So we can apply the preceding paragraph with $\mathcal{F}=\{\pi_X, \pi_Y\}$ to deduce that any $h:W\to X\times Y$ is continuous iff $\pi_X\circ h,  \pi_Y\circ h$ are. Note that something similar can be said for products of more than two spaces. Indeed, in the product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ endowed with its product topology, a function $h:W\to \prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is continuous iff each $\pi_{X_i}\circ h$ is continuous. In this case, we can apply the preceding paragraph with $\mathcal{F}=\{\pi_{X_i}:i\in I\}$.
Using this characterization, in order to show that $i_x$ is continuous, it is sufficient to show that $\pi_X\circ i_x$ and $\pi_Y\circ i_x$ are both continuous. But for any $y\in Y$, $\pi_X\circ i_x(y)=\pi_X(x,y)=x$, so $\pi_X\circ i_x$ is constant and therefore continuous, and $\pi_Y\circ i_x(y)=\pi_Y(x,y)=y$, so $\pi_Y\circ i_x$ is just the identity function from $Y$ to itself, both times with $\tau_Y$, which is also continuous.

Thank you ,you really help me a lot. At the first time, in the class I misunderstood the $i_x$ is a inclusion, like map X's elements to the product set. Now I know it's not,because X is not subset of $X \times Y$,right? And your "intuition part" is a good description of reason.I have learnt a lot ,thank you so much.

That's correct about $i_x$. Let's exclude the case $X=\varnothing$ (because it's pathological and often the definition of topological space requires non-emptiness). The product $X\times Y$ has lots of "parallel" copies of $X$, but $X$ itself isn't a subset of $X\times Y$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, each vertical line in the plane is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}$. For a fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y\mapsto (x,y)$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ with one such vertical line.

More generally, $X\times Y = \bigcup_{x\in X}{x}\times Y$ is a union of a lot of homeomorphic copies of $Y$. Each is canonically identifiable with $Y$, but none of them is actually $Y$.

That's a really nice view making me comprehend product topology deeper.

Sorry, I have another question about your answer.Why is $i_x$ continuous by the definition of product topology?

My response was too long for a comment, so I edited my answer.

OK,I know it.Thanks a lot

Our teacher called it "universal property of the product topology" in the class.
